# what factors determine "catch up speed" on Edge after a network outage

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I have a customer with IoT Edge deployed to manufacturing plants in remote areas with spotty internet.  They have leaf devices sending messages to IOT Edge and then to IoT Hub.  They frequently have small outages (5, 10, 15 minutes).  They often need to make timely decisions based on the data that makes it to IOT Hub from the plants.  They've noticed, if they have a 15 minute outage, it can take anywhere from 15-30 minutes afterwards for IOT Edge to catch up.

Besides network speed itself, what are the factors that would influence that..  For example
- if we were hitting throttling based on their number of iot hub units, would that be surfaced in the edgeHub logs?
- if disk, network, etc can keep up, does edgeHub pretty much upload data as fast as possible (given throttling), or are there any other limits imposed by default?
- What is the default connection retry policy in edgeHub? is the same exponential backoff policy in the C# SDK?  If so, could that be the case that if I have a 15 minute outage, that it's taking edgeHub a while after network recovery to 'try again'? If so, is that policy configurable in edgeHub?  (via ENV variable or something?)

Any other things to check?